# How to use spark connect interceptors?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use a custom interceptor following the documentation present [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#server-configuration). I just have a simple interceptor showed bellow:

```java
package interceptorserver;

import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCall.Listener;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;

public class Interceptor implements ServerInterceptor{

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }
}
```

However, when I compile this code and send this to spark connect with the following command:

```
./start-connect-server.sh \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.4.1 \
    --jars Interceptor.jar \
    --conf spark.connect.grpc.interceptor.classes=interceptorserver.Interceptor
```

I get the following error:

```
23/07/29 01:17:00 ERROR SparkConnectServer: Error starting Spark Connect server
org.apache.spark.SparkException: [CONNECT.INTERCEPTOR_RUNTIME_ERROR] Generic Spark Connect error. Error instantiating GRPC interceptor: class interceptorserver.Interceptor cannot be cast to class org.sparkproject.connect.grpc.ServerInterceptor (interceptorserver.Interceptor and org.sparkproject.connect.grpc.ServerInterceptor are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader @a5272be)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectInterceptorRegistry$.createInstance(SparkConnectInterceptorRegistry.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectInterceptorRegistry$.$anonfun$createConfiguredInterceptors$4(SparkConnectInterceptorRegistry.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
...
```

First I thought that `org.sparkproject.connect.grpc.ServerInterceptor` is different than `io.grpc.ServerInterceptor` but when I've checked the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/connector/connect/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/connect/service/SparkConnectInterceptorRegistry.scala#L66C33-L66C50) and I saw that Spark is indeed using `io.grpc.ServerInterceptor`, besides that, the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#server-configuration) itself says to use `io.grpc.ServerInterceptor` so my second thought was: "Does my class really implement the `io.grpc.ServerInterceptor` interface?", then I did the following dummy test

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package interceptorserver;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class LibraryTest {
    @Test public void someLibraryMethodReturnsTrue() {
        Interceptor classUnderTest = new Interceptor();
        Assert.assertTrue(classUnderTest instanceof io.grpc.ServerInterceptor);
    }
}
```

And my test passed. So my question is: What I'm doing wrong? Why my class can't be casted to the needed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If you made it work.

I have succeeded it, thanks to the comment from hage. Although, due to my own lack of knowledge, it took me a bit to understand it.
I will share it in case it helps someone.

As hage mentioned, Spark shades the GRPC classes.

I copied the configuration of the `maven-shade-plugin` from the `spark-connect-server` project to my own pom.xml.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/connector/connect/server/pom.xml#L284

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spark.shade.packageName>org.sparkproject</spark.shade.packageName>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>3.5.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-connect-common_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.example:interceptor</include>
                            <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
                            <include>io.grpc:*:</include>
                            <include>com.google.protobuf:*</include>

                            <!--
                              The dependencies below are not added in SBT because SBT add them all
                              as assembly build.
                            -->
                            <include>com.google.android:annotations</include>
                            <include>com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos</include>
                            <include>io.perfmark:perfmark-api</include>
                            <include>org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations</include>
                            <include>com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations</include>
                            <include>com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations</include>
                            <include>org.checkerframework:checker-qual</include>
                            <include>com.google.code.gson:gson</include>
                            <include>org.apache.spark:spark-connect-common_${scala.binary.version}</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.guava</shadedPattern>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.common.**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.thirdparty</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.guava</shadedPattern>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.thirdparty.**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.protobuf</shadedPattern>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.protobuf.**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>io.grpc</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.grpc</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>

                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>android.annotation</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.android_annotation</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>io.perfmark</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.io_perfmark</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.animal_sniffer</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.j2objc.annotations</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.j2objc_annotations</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.errorprone.annotations</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.errorprone_annotations</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.checkerframework</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.checkerframework</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.gson</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.gson</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>

                        <!--
                          For `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos`, do not directly define pattern
                          as `common.google`, otherwise, otherwise, the relocation result may be uncertain due
                          to the change of rule order.
                        -->
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.api</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.api</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.cloud</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.cloud</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.geo</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.geo</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.logging</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.logging</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.longrunning</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.longrunning</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.rpc</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.rpc</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.type</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.connect.google_protos.type</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My interceptor is like Matheus's.

```
package org.example;

import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;

public class Interceptor implements ServerInterceptor {


    public Interceptor() {
    }

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
    }

}
```

This way it has worked for me without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue recently.

The thing is, that the Spark project shades the gRPC classes. You will have to do the same in your project.

You can read on this here: https://lists.apache.org/thread/t95pcdh5zw2154pc3cfhv27pv7nltdnf